# Помогите расшифровать строку

Tags: веб-программирование, кодировка, decode

Есть такая вот строка, которая передается в javascript код, а он ее расшифровывает как-то и с ней работает, скорее всего после расшифровки должен получиться json. Я думал это base64, но у меня что-то не получается. Буду благодарен за помощь и информацию как ее расшифровывать.

Вот сама строка:

```
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
```

Comment: покажете, откуда эта строка?

Comment: Я попробовал на питоне расшифровать, тоже ботва какая-то получается

Comment: @Jack_oS вот от сюда http://exam.pewete.ru:9001/!/scorms.ecp/23/%D0%9F%D0%91%D0%9F%20312.7_1/index.html в исходном коде страницы. `var presInfo =`

Comment: да, ее потом передают в PresentationPlayer.start(presInfo, "content", "playerView", onPlayerInit, savedPresentationState); может, подгружает скрипт презентации? что вы хотели в ней расшифровать?

Comment: @Jack_oS там json массив скорее всего в котором указаны все пути к файлам которые задействованы в презентации (картинки, css, js и тд)

Comment: чтобы что? собирать по кусочкам листы презентации? или нужны изображения?

Comment: @Jack_oS для того чтобы скачать все эти ресурсы скриптом. так как там все ресурсы подгружаются динамически, и **wget** не видит их. А расшифруя этот массив я смогу скачивать все файлы (так как буду знать пути к ним)

Comment: трудозатратно как-то... не проще ли скриптом открывать очередной лист презентации, делать скрин и сохранять как изображение?

Comment: @Jack_oS нет, так как презентации нужно скачивать массово, а не только одну эту) для этого и нужно узнать пути к ресурсам чтобы скрипт все сам скачивал

Comment: для этого нужны адреса презентаций и selenium ))

Comment: тогда боюсь единственный путь изучать player.js из которого судя по всему вызываемая функция. А он сжат, так что это то еще развлечение. И да, это base64, но в нем явно не json а двоичные данные, которые та js функция как то раскодирует. может там какое нибудь сжатие применено, а может и дополнительно шифровано

Comment: @Mike то что он сжат это не проблема, есть же сервисы типа unminify

Answer (score 2):

сохраняем в текстовый файл и распаковываем base64

```
base64 -d data.b64 > file.bin
```

теперь натравим на него file

```
file file.bin
```

и получаем

```
file.bin: zlib compressed data
```

о, это уже интересно. Распакуем

```
base64 -d data.b64 | zlib-flate -uncompress
```

и получаем что то похожее на json. Похожее, потому что он не полный. В нем о организации каких то модулей и ликвидации каких то последствий. Но это тема отдельного вопроса.

Если утилиты zlib-flate нет, можно распаковать и другими способами. Например, скорее всего есть openssl

```
base64 -d file.bin | openssl zlib -d
```

Comment: Вы просто гений!! Огромное спасибо, строка раскодирована как и хотелось. Очень прошу пояснить какие технологии тут использовались, и **самый главный вопрос** - возможно ли всю эту процедуру раскодирования произвести, например, средствами **php** ?

Comment: @iKey, вам же все написали, разбирайтесь.

Comment: в вопросе я описал, какие "технологии использовались". И да, это все можно сделать на php

Comment: Вам нужно две функции base64_decode и zlib_decode  для распаковки zlib. Похоже, там прям две сроки будет

Comment: @iKey покажите хоть, во что раскодировалось?

Comment: То есть после base64_decode мы получим zlib, верно? И потом просто декодировать zlib нужно, да?

Comment: Печатать сюда 40 килобайт json?